# 2 different lists on a page - Master and 2nd version

Tags: css, list

So I have a master ul li list for the rest of the site. but in a particular block I have a list that looks different. I was asked can this be "locked" as a style for just that area. If they erase the list the style class disappears. I am not quite sure what to tell them except do not erase the list...lol. (example and css below)

If it matters... this is Sharepoint 2013. But could be any CMS.
Thanks for the assist all!
Leo

(Example Block)

```
    <h3>News Releases</h3>
<ul class="our-posts-spotlight-df99" style="padding-left: 0px;">
   <li>CFO named one of Canada&#39;s Top 40 Under 40</li>
   <li>Reports its First Quarter Financial Results for 2019</li>
   <li>Launches new safety campaign: Downed lines are deadly</li>
</ul> 
<a class="position-spotlight" href="#">...more</a><br/>

(CSS)
.our-posts-df99 ul li{
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #707070;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should see features of you cms in content saving category. Sometimes when my cms generate some css code, and i want to hardcode it, i copy this code in developer tools and paste inline like a code in a richtext editor.
But when you paste css, you need switch on a code mode =)
Sorry for my English =)